# Save BGR image with cv2.imwrite

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have a 2D numpy array which it's values are float between [-4, 3].
**cv2.imshow** shows this array as a BGR Image, but when I saved it with **cv2.imwrite** it was completely black. Then I found that I have to multiply the array to 255 to save it with **imwrite**, but in this case the image saved in RGB format, but I want to save the BGR image which shown by **cv2.imshow**.
What should I do?

Comment: Practically all image formats use RGB ordering. What format (file extension) do you want to use?

Comment: I'm saving the image as a PNG file

Comment: PNG files are incapable of storing floats. You'll likely need TIFF or PFM.

Comment: Also, the ordering within any image file you save (PNG, BMP, GIF, JPG) is not really relevant because OpenCV converts it on-the-fly as it reads or writes. The order is standardised to RGB so other applications can correctly interpret your images.

Comment: Images in floating point format must have values in range [0,1]. Ones with 8 bit unsigned need to be in range [0,255]. Multiplying values in range [-4,3] by 255 will still leave you with invalid values (or worse, cause overflow, completely trashing the data.)

Comment: You could use `np.save()` https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to adjust the value of all arrays. The pixels are between -4 and 3 so you have to do this:

```
img = img - min_val
img = img*255.0/(max_val - min_val)
```

which in your case it would be like:

```
img = img+4
img = img*255/7.0
```

then convert your img to 8bit unsinged int and save it with `imwrite` (no need to mess with BGR or RGB, opencv handles it by itself)

Comment: After trynig this method, the output looks like matplotlib imsave. So also this method is like RGB format (not BGR). Thanks

Comment: If you want to substitute R with B, do a split and get 3 separate channels and merge those with reverse order.

Comment: Note that this approach will potentially lead to *"banding"* if you try and save a smooth ramp (gradient) ranging from say 0..1 over a large image because you only have 8-bit resolution. If that is a problem, since you are using PNG you can save a 16-bit file by changing all the 255's in the formula to 65,535 and converting to 16-bit unsigned short before saving as PNG.

Comment: @Mark Stechell yes of course this method would make some of the data to be lost but I mentioned the simplest way. He can save PNG as you said or save the original array as xml or txt file.

Answer (score 4):

So, basically you want to convert your image from RGB to BGR image.

This can be done by using cv2.cvtColor() function.

```
result_BGR = cv2.cvtColor(RGB_image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
cv2.imwrite('PATH', result_BGR)
```

Comment: I did that with this code.
**image = cv2.cvtColor(image.astype('float32'), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
cv2.imwrite('path', image*255)**
but the result is the same (saved as RGB!!!)

Comment: You are using ```cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB``` which converts BGR image to RGB.

But here, we want to convert RGB to BGR. So, you should use ```cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR``` . Have a look on my answer again. It will help you. :)

Comment: well, that was a mistake in writing. My code is:
*image = cv2.cvtColor(image.astype('float32'), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)*
*cv2.imwrite('path', image*255)*
but still the image doesn't changed !!!